# Create horizontal scroll on Android TV

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I am trying to create a horizontal scroll menu just like the bottom of the screenshot.

Since this is on **Android TV**, each item should be able to show highlighted focus and the entire menu should scroll when necessary when users press LEFT/RIGHT on **D-PAD**.

[image]

On mobile this can be easily achieved with RecyclerView but on Android TV I have learned that it is better to stick to Leanback SDK. I have found that `androidx.leanback.widget.HorizontalGridView` is the widget to use.

My problem is, whenever I press LEFT/RIGHT, HorizontalGridView always scroll back to position 0 as seen here https://youtu.be/Y3mxUaCQYdY

Here's my code

**layout.xml**

```
    <androidx.leanback.widget.HorizontalGridView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_menu"
        android:layout_width="430dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

**fragment**

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false)
        mHgv = view?.findViewById(R.id.horizontal_menu) as HorizontalGridView
        mHgv.setNumRows(1)
        mHgv.setItemSpacing(20)
        mHgv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL)
        
        val presenter = MenuPresenter()
        val objectAdapter = ArrayObjectAdapter(presenter)
        initData()
        objectAdapter.addAll(0, dataList)
        val bridgeAdapter = ItemBridgeAdapter(objectAdapter)
        mHgv.adapter = bridgeAdapter
        mHgv.requestFocus()
        FocusHighlightHelper.setupHeaderItemFocusHighlight(bridgeAdapter)
        return view
    }

private fun initData() {
        if (!this::dataList.isInitialized) {
            dataList = mutableListOf()
            for (i in 0 until 20) {
                dataList.add(i)
            }
        }
    }
```

If I use my mouse I can scroll fine, but if I use D-PAD's LEFT/RIGHT it will cause the aforementioned problem.
I have also tried to set horizontal LinearLayout manager to HorizontalGridView but not working too.

Please help me, I have been stuck on this problem for 4 days.

thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing the jumping that you're seeing. It sounds like something is stealing the focus, but I don't see anything in the code you've provided that would cause that behavior. You might consider trying a ListRow instead of HorizontalGridView.

Comment: I figured what the problem was.
1. Remove android:focusable="true" and android:focusableInTouchMode="true" from layout.xml.
2. Add the same code to MenuPresenter's onCreateViewHolder